# Recommend hosting with fast MySQL database please

Tags: web-hosting, mysql, recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am frustrated to no end with my current hosting provider, mediaTemple. Yes, they are flashy, and have some decent degree of flexibility with their GS plan, which I have. But anytime I install a site that needs a database, it is slow. like really slow. Taking anywhere from 10 - 15 seconds just to load a page.

I would host in house, but there are a lot of complications that come with a LAMP server that I don't want to deal with. Honestly, I'd rather spend the time developing.

What can you recommend?

Comment: Are you sure it is the database server and not something else on the server or the code? What kind of benchmarking have you done?

Comment: This is always an issue with mediaTemple. Whether I install wordpress, drupal, or write a simple script such as user registration, it is extremely slow. I've had MT for 2 years and thought that maybe it was me... doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I've run trace route on multiple domains to see if that was the case for slowness, no tests other than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're load times might come from your bandwidth allowance.

[Host Monster](http://hostmonster.com/)
[Web Faction](http://webfaction.com/)

I've used Host Monster for all of my projects. It has a huge bandwidth allowance including up to 5 Tb of storage, and it's pretty cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I use hostek.com to host dozens of my sites. I run ColdFusion 9 and SQL Server, but they have many other configurations available, including PHP and MySQL.

I have a developer account. I get five distinct sites for $25 per month. Each sites gets its own database.  Additional sites are like $4 each.

I have had zero issues with the company over the course of a year.

You can check one of my sites out here:

http://www.franchise-minnesota.info/